# Flink Stateful Functions with an existing Flink application

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-statefun

I'd appreciate some advice around the use of Stateful functions.
We are currently using Flink whereby we consume from a number of kafka streams, aggregate, run a computation and then output to a new stream.
The problem is that the computation element is provided by a different team whose language of choice is Python. We would like to provide them with the ability to develop and update their component independently of the streaming elements.
Initially, we just ported their code to Java.
Stateful functions seem to offer an alternative here whereby we would keep some of our functionality as is and host the model as a Stateful Function in Python. I'm wondering however, if there is any advantage to this over just hosting the computation module on its own pipeline and using AsyncFunction in Flink to interact with it.
If we were to move to Stateful functions I can't help feeling that we are adding complexity without using its power but I may be missing some important considerations around speed and resilience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to begin by noting that Stateful Functions does have a DataStream interop module. This means you can use StateFun to handle the Python functions of your pipeline without rewriting the entire Flink Job.

That said, what advantages does Stateful Functions bring over using AsyncIO and doing it yourself?

1. Automated handling of connections, batching, back-pressuring, and retries. Even if you are using a single python function and no state, Stateful Functions has been heavily optimized to be as fast and efficient as possible with continual improvements from the community that you will get to leverage for free. StateFun has more sophisticated back pressuring and retry mechanisms in place than AsyncIO that you would need to redevelop on your own.
2. Higher level APIs. StateFuns Python SDK (and others) provide well defined, typed apis that are easy to develop against. The other team you are working with will only require a few lines of glue code to integrate with StateFun while the project will handle the transport protocols for you.
3. State! As the name of the project implies, stateful functions are well stateful. Python functions can maintain state and you will get Flink's exactly once guarantees out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think we'll fire ahead and do an investigation so, it seems to offer a lot of what we were going to have to write out of the box

Comment: Hi Seth, I have started hooking up our application but can only find examples of using Kafka as the ingress. The documentation suggests that http can be used as well but I can't find any examples, would you be able to point me in the right direction?